# 2012 Community Moderator Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary. I will be working with candidates to schedule a time appropriate for them.

***The Town Hall Chat will take place on Monday, July 30th, at 21:00:00Z UTC / This is at 5pm EDT - one hour after the new phase starts***

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=7&day=30&year=2012&hour=21&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/4302/home-improvement-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

**[join the room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4302/home-improvement-town-hall-chat)**

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at July 30th - August 2nd. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=diy.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: The digest has been posted at: [Town Hall Chat Digest](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/629/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)