# 2012 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest

Tags: discussion, election

The following is a "digest" version of the [2012 Moderator Election Town Hall Chat](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/610/2012-community-moderator-town-hall-chat). The format, [as described on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests), is one *answer* to this question *for every question* asked in the Town Hall, containing all the candidate's answers to that question.

**To view the digest chronologically, please sort the answers by "oldest"**.

If you have questions or comments about this, **please do not answer this question** as the answers are designed to be used for the questions from the Town hall itself. Instead, please ask on [the parent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests) or in [the Town Hall Discussion Room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

If you see any corrections which need to be made to this digest, or if you were a candidate who was unable to attend the town hall and would like your answers included, please @GraceNote or @TimStone [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4302/home-improvement-town-hall-chat) and let us know!

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Tim Stone] [Tim Stone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12325/tim-stone) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572492#5572492):* **Do you feel like a representative percentage of the community participates in your site's meta? Based on that, how strongly do you think feedback presented on meta should factor into your decision making as a moderator?**

---

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572536#5572536):**  Meta participation is a bit low on the site, but we typically don't have a lot of issues that require the use of Meta

- **[image: Vebjorn Ljosa] [Vebjorn Ljosa](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/16091/vebjorn-ljosa) [noted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572547#5572547):** We have scope issues (shopping questions, etc.) that we have not really resolved yet.

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572543#5572543):**  I can't speak for other sites, but on DIY, most of the meta comes from a small percentage of users and is typically specific to question types; I haven't really seen too much regarding moderator feedback. That being said, because it is only a small percentange of well known users, I value their input very much so and would certainly take it into consideration!

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572549#5572549):**  I think meta is very important but is mostly missed by daily users. As a moderator the meta is a very important way to make sure decisions are within the majority of agreement before doing anything drastic

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572552#5572552):**  The meta discussions **must** guide the moderators, as meta is likely to be populated by the most active core users from the community. One of the mod roles should be to try and increase participation on meta, but at the end of the day when a site is moving well, there may not be much need for a high level of meta activity.

- **[image: Vebjorn Ljosa] [Vebjorn Ljosa](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/16091/vebjorn-ljosa) [noted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572560#5572560):**  I don't think increasing meta activity is a goal in itself.

  **[image: Vebjorn Ljosa] [Vebjorn Ljosa](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/16091/vebjorn-ljosa) [added](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572585#5572585):** Echoing Jeff Atwood, it is a sign of health when I site does not have the need for huge wars on Meta

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572608#5572608):**  Since even I haven't spent enough time on meta, I don't think there's a good representative percentage there. For the most part, I believe we're easy going enough to handle a majority of the questions without much conflict or debate. But when that doesn't happen, it's important to follow up with the chat room, and get the question highlighted in the bulletin board.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573025#5573025):* **How much time do you expect to spend per day performing moderation duties? Or will it just be "as it comes," whenever you have the time or get in the mood?**

---

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573061#5573061):**  Whenever I see the icon light up in the tool bar, or as I see activity on questions that requires intervention. I probably refresh a dozen times per day.

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573068#5573068):**  If I were chosen as a moderator I would spend more time. As it is I am busy during the day and only sign on during silent spots. But I still try and provide decent content.

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573071#5573071):**  Currently my go-to times for most SE sites are between 0700 and 0930, lunchtime, and after 1900 (British time :-) )- or if I am commuting I do tend to sign in on my Android

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5575034#5575034):**  Since it sounds like moderation is a light duty job on DIY, I'd probably not spend much time on moderation tasks. But since I already spend way too much time on the site, dedicating time to moderation tasks (if there was an influx) would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572280#5572280):* **With a diamond after your name, everything you say and do on the site will be perceived in a different way. How do you plan to handle this, especially when having discussions about site policy and scope decisions?**

---

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572315#5572315):**  I already accept this from my mod role on Sec.SE - it doesn't change my behaviour. I always want my behaviour on SE sites to be seen as positive and supportive.

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572327#5572327):**  Well, I think there is an onus on moderators to really think twice before replying to ensure that their response is fair, reasonable and respectful of the OP. There is definitely an expectation of professionalism from moderators and this is especially true on the SE networks which IMO, are known for high quality content. It is my goal to maintain that view.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572340#5572340):**  When it comes to the binding votes, I'll hold back my decisions until there's community agreement for all but the most clear issues. For other topics, I'll make sure to point out what's my own opinion if I don't feel it represents the overall community.

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572352#5572352):**  I think that I will spend more time into investigating site rules and asking for advice before acting on behaviour that might be off topic or bordering on being to wide. As always I will keep on getting rid of spam content, flag inappropriate questions and always help new comers to the site- with edits, up votes and a welcoming comment

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572354#5572354):**  I'll continue to do as I've always done, and base comments on what I think is best for the community.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/40/chrisf) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572314#5572314):* **What do you see as being the moderators role on a relatively small site like DIY?**

---

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572355#5572355):**  the same as it would on a large site :) To keep the content on-topic, appropriate, and guide users through the process of adhering to policies!

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572360#5572360):**  Helping the community. Thus far DIY hasn't had the trouble some of the larger sites have had with bad behaviour, so my assumption is that moderator activities will include helping the site grow, as well as clean-up, exception handling etc.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572373#5572373):**  Mostly helping new users stay within our format with comments, edits, and moving things around for users that don't have the rep to put it in the correct location (e.g. comments in the answer box).

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572384#5572384):**  Increase site traffic, clean up content, help new users ask effective questions.

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572385#5572385):**  I would have figured trying to add link backs to DIY to other sites, such as my personal blogs, other forums that ranked higher than DIY.SE for specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572364#5572364):* **How would you handle a user who makes valuable content contributions, but causes significant disruptions to the site in other ways?**

---

- **[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [asked for clarification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572377#5572377):**  Can you be more specific as to what you mean by disruptions?

  **[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [clarified](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572397#5572397):**  Ill demeanor in comments, starts being abusive in chat, gets extremely confrontational and contradictory... that sort of stuff

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572386#5572386):**  initially, use comments, or discussion in chat, then moving to editing their posts, and moving to suspensions if required. Have had to use this a couple of times on Sec.SE and had good success in changing the user's behaviour.

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572389#5572389):**  Hell ban.

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572424#5572424):**  Leave comments to the user, and try to encourage them to change their behaviour.

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572415#5572415):**  Well I think you have to start by removing offending comments. Sometimes people are just too quick to hit "submit" and don't really think their postst through. IF it became a chronic problem, first step would be to address it directly with the user, and if still not resolved, would seek a ban or other suspension type (assuming these exist on SE)

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572421#5572421):**  As it is impossible to contact a member directly to try and establish the problem that are being cause. A ban or some sort of flag would be inevitable.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572429#5572429):**  So far, we've been lucky to not have this issue, to the best of my knowledge. I believe in comments first, then edits, and if necessary, a temporary timeout.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/40/chrisf) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572383#5572383):* **Give the physical nature of the site's subject matter, what would you do if you saw someone posting potentially dangerous advice?**

---

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572404#5572404):**  The same thing I've always done, comment why it's dangerous, and down vote.

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572418#5572418):**  I'd want to check with others first - the community here is much more experienced than I, but if it was confirmed it was dangerous I would want to downvote and comment. If they had a high vote so were appearing at the top, I'd take guidance, but potentially delete to remove the answer.

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572433#5572433):**  If it was "uber dangerous" I would remove it immediately before other people have time to see it and try it.  But if its just poor advice then downvote as well as providing a comment with references to other questions/answers/information as to why this answer is incorrect and dangerous

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572450#5572450):**  As this is DIY- any advice is potentially dangerous. When I feel that an answer or comment can lead to some sort of harm- it boils me up and I must place advice against it- or atleast provide a safer alterantive

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572460#5572460):**  Comment and delete if it's clearly life threatening. Otherwise, I would comment with a description of why I feel it's dangerous and ask the user to consider editing or deleting.

- **[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [remarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572480#5572480):**  I think dangerous should not be deleted.. because other users might not know that danger. It should be cleary marked as dangerous and adequate alternatives provided. In health and safety.. you learn what not to do..

  **[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572494#5572494):**  So far, I've yet to see anything that would meet my criteria for deletion, but you make a great point.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572455#5572455):* **New users often are not accustomed to the Stack Exchange system, and sometimes struggle to present themselves properly, either in the way they use the site or their attitude. How willing are you to work with "problematic" users, and at what point do you decide that someone isn't worth the effort?**

---

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572481#5572481):**  I have no problem guiding new users, and helping them understand how the site works.  They are always worth the effort.

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572491#5572491):**  I am always patient, and willing to give almost everyone the chance. There may be a couple of exceptions (known SE network-wide :-) but even for those I'd rather comment in the first instance to try and guide them

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572506#5572506):**  At first, assuming the questions were still relevant, I would at first edit the questions to remove the problematic areas and leave a comment as to why the edits were made - sometimes people just need a nudge in the right direction. As long as the questions were still relevant, and not illegal then I'd try to work with the user to improve the question quality.  If they are just completely off (racist, demeaning, etc.) then I would only give it a couple tries to resolve then seek to ban.

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572509#5572509):**  Many users are one time visitors that might return much later or refer a friend. On other SE sites there are users that abuse the forums and never contribute back. I think its best to try and make that users questions more constructive even if he himself is relucatant to the idea of SE. I do not think any bans are in order. Sometimes people ask good questions.. but could not be bothered to contribute back. A good question is worth 2 answers!

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572525#5572525):**  I search for value in either the questions or answers from the user. When there's value to the community, I believe in working with the user until it's clear to me they are intentionally making things difficult. At that point, I would review with other moderators before taking any action against anyone.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Tim Stone] [Tim Stone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12325/tim-stone) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572526#5572526):* **When you see a question with major issues (poorly-written, argumentative, etc.), what tool do you reach for first?**

---

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572546#5572546):**  edit

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572561#5572561):**  I reach for brain power, then google built in spell checker.

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572572#5572572):**  First tool is my brain :) When I find such questions, I always try to see if I can figure out what is being asked at the root of the question. If it is clear I will edit the question to highlight the relevant parts and remove unnecessary info, especially if it is argumentative in nature.  If I don't understand what the OP was asking then I will post a comment asking the OP to edit and clarify

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572587#5572587):**  edit - first tool, every time

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572651#5572651):**  If I understand the question, then I frequently favor the edit button first to improve the question. If there's disagreement with my change, it can always be rolled back. I often comment to explain the reason for the edit. But any time it's not clear, I'll start with a comment to request more details.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Tim Stone] [Tim Stone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12325/tim-stone) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572619#5572619):* **Is there anything about the way the site is currently run that you would like to change? If so, what would you try to change if you were to become a moderator, and why?**

---

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572632#5572632):**  Nothing site works great.

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572641#5572641):**  you know, I think the DIY site is really a gem among the SE sites. It seems to run really really smoothly.  All the mods are doing a great job! I hope if I win I can live up to them!

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572642#5572642):**  I don't think so - the mods do an excellent job as it is. My goal is to support them as we grow, whether or not I become a mod here.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572708#5572708):**  I think the moderation here has been fantastic and my biggest hope is to take some of the load off of the existing moderators so they can focus more on the complicated issues, and enjoy some more free time.

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572717#5572717):**  I love the way SE runs- even though there are things that could need chaning.. implemeintgin those changes can be very difficult. I would seek guidance from meta users

- **[image: Vebjorn Ljosa] [Vebjorn Ljosa](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/16091/vebjorn-ljosa) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572735#5572735):**  Any particular things that need changing that you would like to elaborate on?

  **[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572801#5572801):**  At this stage. I cannot remember.. but there was something

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572627#5572627):* **Moderating is a lot of work. Do you expect to be able to keep answering questions or will you spend all your time here moderating?**

---

- **[image: Vebjorn Ljosa] [Vebjorn Ljosa](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/16091/vebjorn-ljosa) [noted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572640#5572640):**  Actually moderating this particular site is not a lot of work.

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572638#5572638):**  There is always time to help users who have questions.

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572649#5572649):**  I expect to spend more time on the site as a moderator and definitely  try and stay longer to resolve any problems that have been spotted

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572667#5572667):**  I think if the site gets to the point that time spent on moderation exceeds everything else then there is a larger root problem that needs to be addressed - so I really do hope I can continue to answer lots of questions!

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572669#5572669):**  I would hope to spend a bit more time here, but that would all be moderation. My answers are only on things I tend to know well, and like I said, there are many here with greater DIY knowledge than I so my questions and answers probably won't suffer at all.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572755#5572755):**  I have a fair bit of free time these days, and most of that is working from home. So I expect to be able to handle the additional workload without reducing how many answers I give. I personally spend more time reviewing other people's answers than I do providing my own anyway, since there's always something one can learn.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572668#5572668):* **How do you feel about doing all this hard work for this site as a Moderator, while the larger entity benefits financially on traffic based revenue?**

---

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572713#5572713):**  That's life in the real world, isn't it?

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572779#5572779):**  I spend time working as a mod already for no financial gain (if you exclude a couple of excellent t-shirts:-) - my take on it is threefold: 1) I spend a lot of time as a mentor anyway so this doesn't change my day, 2) it is good public recognition, and 3) I kind of believe in karma - I enjoy helping others as they have helped me

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572780#5572780):**  Wait, someone's making money one this? :) I don't mind SE making money since I have received much more value than I could ever give back, mostly from SO, but also from all the tips and tricks I've learned on DIY.

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5574931#5574931):**  No problem working hard while others profit. Been doing it all my life.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572820#5572820):* **Two highly respected members of the community get in a comment war on a question. They both flag each other's comments and are cussing and it is clear that this is beyond a heated argument. What do you do, what don't you do?**

---

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572847#5572847):**  Delete the cussing and suggest they initially go to chat. If that doesn't work straight away, if they are respected they should know better, so the threat of a suspension would be the next step, closely followed by an actual short suspension if they don't immediately sort themselves out.

**[image: Steven] [Steven](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30077/steven) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572851#5572851):**  Remove all of the comments and temporarily lock the question until it cools off. Send them both a message asking them to respect eachother and the community and to not tarnish they well respective status with a comment war.  I would not get involved in the comment war nor make threats like "your account will be suspended"

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572872#5572872):**  Across several forums I have not seen this. But if it were to elevate to such a situation it is pretty clear there is a personal dis like between the moderators; It has to be as moderators should set the example of keeping things clean and help each other out. Possibly suggest they start a meta question..

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572876#5572876):**  Ask them to take a breather, move it to a chat room, and voluntarily delete their comments. Otherwise, give them a short timeout and delete the comments myself if other mods agree.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572892#5572892):**  And also point out that they are talking to another living person, even if they are on the other side of the computer screen.

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5574954#5574954):**  Delete all inappropriate comments, and warn the users that if they cannot be respectful to the community they will be put on timeout until they can behave.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572863#5572863):* **You strongly disagree with an action taken by a fellow moderator. How do you proceed?**

---

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572907#5572907):**  As a fellow moderator try and communicate in the meta forum. I would not delete anything just because I disagree with it - I would most likely leave my own opinion on the subject after a few days of unresponsiveness

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572910#5572910):**  If it can't be resolved by a quick discussion with that mod in meta, I'd usually ask for guidance from the wider mod community over on TL.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572911#5572911):**  Take it to the moderator chat area or meta depending on how sensitive it is.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5572935#5572935):**  Or if I mildly disagree with @ChrisF's UK spell check, I'll revert it back to the US spelling and leave a comment. :)

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5574997#5574997):**  I'd probably start a private chat with the mod. If we could not come to an agreement in private, I would post a question on Meta to see how the community feels about the situation.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573001#5573001):* **What is your preferred screw type?**

---

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573008#5573008):**  Badum tschsshshshs - I mean, flat head, obviously :-)

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573026#5573026):**  The correct answer is a framing nail gun :)

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5575005#5575005):**  Torx.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573091#5573091):* **How well do you handle being down voted?**

---

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573108#5573108):**  With a reason, I handle it as a learning experience. Without a reason, I handle it with confusion.

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573119#5573119):**  I handle it the same way as giving out down votes. Not very well and hope for it to be as little as possible.

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573133#5573133):**  Very well - I tend to look at why - to see if there was an improvement needed, and if I can, I do. So far, I think my main downvotes have been from not spotting a duplicate before I ask my question - which just shows I should put more effort into the search function :-) I don't take it personally though.

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5575081#5575081):**  If there is no explanation, I would post a comment asking what was not correct in the post. Once I had an explanation, I would make corrections to the post.  The number one goal of all questions, answers, and sometimes comments is to provide the most accurate information possible.

Answer (score 0):

### *[Niall C. http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c310c0454f3734954e59094072c3ddad?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c310c0454f3734954e59094072c3ddad?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Niall C.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/568/niall-c) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573129#5573129):* **With one exception, the candidates have no prior experience of moderatorship and little involvement on meta.SO.  How do you plan to learn the ropes?**

---

**[BMitch http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b6975c494d3d9c404dd3d7af2edf3133?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b6975c494d3d9c404dd3d7af2edf3133?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573148#5573148):**  To start with, I'll use the cheat sheet, which should be required reading for anyone that's elected: [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet)

**[ppumkin http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2cc90cec13a0801926f6ea3396f22d17?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2cc90cec13a0801926f6ea3396f22d17?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573161#5573161):**  It definitely means Ill be asking more questions to existing moderators.. but first I will be clicking on that cheat sheet just posted.

**[Rory Alsop http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/af1ed0816ed5a2164a4e343ad09309ad?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/af1ed0816ed5a2164a4e343ad09309ad?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573191#5573191):**  The cheat sheet is useful for all moderators, not just those new to the role. Meta and the Teacher's Lounge are very useful resources as well.

**[Tester101 http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0038a597da931baa88ec1dcbdc504a87?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0038a597da931baa88ec1dcbdc504a87?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5575102#5575102):**  Meta and chat are how I learn about any feature of the site, so those would still be my go to tools.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Vebjorn Ljosa] [Vebjorn Ljosa](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/16091/vebjorn-ljosa) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573162#5573162):*  **As a follow-up to the previous question, do any of the candidate have experience moderating other forms of online communities, such as public mailing lists?**

---

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573188#5573188):**  Yes during the years I have moderated various sites, mailing lists, forums blogs and other publicly and private bulletins.

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573200#5573200):**  I'm on my HOA board, which means keeping a lot of differing opinions happy. I've also organized teams at my local Habitat for Humanity chapter, which is a lot like herding cats in a mine field. For the Habitat group, I've setup their internal mailing list and help with adds/removes.

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573229#5573229):**  A little bit outside SE - blogs and mailing lists mostly, but my core experience is from the last year and a half as a mod for SE. I also lead two professional communities in Scotland (ISACA and IISP) - but most of my effort for them is offline, managing events, membership, budgets, governance etc.

**[image: Tester101] [Tester101](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1477/tester101) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5575113#5575113):**  I've done a little work with the [Blog](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/), Does that count?

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573163#5573163):* As we approach the end, **closing thoughts from candidates**?

---

**[image: ppumkin] [ppumkin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18709/ppumkin) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573238#5573238):** It has been very pleasant to chat with fellow users and learn more about your views. I have been as honest as possible and hope all the best for everybody. Thank you for your time @GraceNote

**[image: BMitch] [BMitch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15872/bmitch) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573240#5573240):**  Vote early, vote often, and thanks for participating since this is community is for the users.

**[image: Rory Alsop] [Rory Alsop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5573283#5573283):**  I would be delighted to join the mod ranks here, but if not, I'll support whoever does get voted in. Let's keep the site a success.